# How to access nested json params in a post request with Ruby on Rails on the backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to access the json parameters from a form post request in a Ruby on Rails backend controller.  I need to access a model object (carrier-type), in order to get the id.  However, I keep getting the following error.  Can anyone advise how I would access this data?

**Error:**

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass excluded from capture: DSN not set
app_1         |
app_1         | NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
```

**Sample Json Data:**

```
{"_jsonapi"=>
    {"data"=>
        {"attributes"=> {"device"=>mobile},
         "relationships"=>
            {"carrier-type"=>{"data"=>{"id"="1}}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Access Attempt:**

I have tried the following

```
@myParams = params[:_jsonapi];
Rails.logger.info("STARTTIME PARAMS: #{@myParams}")
```

Comment: Is a bit difficult to understand the problem, can you update your question with the output of `Rails.logger.info("PARAMS: #{params}")`?

Comment: PARAMS: {"_jsonapi"=><ActionController::Parameters {"data"=><ActionController::Parameters {"attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {
"device"=>"mobile"} permitted: false>, "relationships"=>{"carrier-type"=>{"data"=>{ "id"=>"1"}}}, "type"=>"devices"} permitted: false>} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"jsonapi/devices", "action"=>"create", "api_version"=>"v2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be trying to access the `id` in the following way

```
params["_jsonapi"]["data"]["relationships"]["carrier-type"]["data"]["id"]
```

this can throw you an error if any of the previous key will not be there in your JSON.

i.e.

```
params["_jsonapi"]["key_that_is_not_present"]["relationships"]["carrier-type"]["data"]["id"]
```

will through error like:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

I would suggest you to use `dig` here.

```
params.dig("_jsonapi", "data", "relationships", "carrier-type", "data", "id")
```

in this way you will not get an error but if any key is not present you will get `nil`
i.e.

```
params.dig("_jsonapi", "random_key")
```

will return `nil`